# Returning the date from varied data, where the date is formatted in text and the days vary digits from 1 to 2

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, substitution

```
Data  -----------------| ----- Formula ---|------------------- Date (Output) ------------------------------ 

(name - Aug 7, 2015) --------------------------------------------------------- 07/08/15


| -'}{[]//-;'; (lots of characters) (name - Aug 7, 2015) -------------------07/08/15
```

the length always varies to a great degree (name also changes - jan 27, 2015)  -  27/01/15

---

```
Varied text (name - Aug 17, 2015) ----------------------------------------- 17/08/15
```

---

The issue with the data is that it uses several characters and varies constantly and that some of the dates are displayed one digit shorter, (e.g. (name - Aug 17, 2015) (name - Aug 7, 2015)) making it difficult to use =right and =mid as the position changes (stopping excel from reading as a date. I have included pictures below as I know my data isn't displayed in a clean way, apologies in advance.)

Here are some of the formulas that I have tried:

---

```
 =DATEVALUE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+1,LEN(A2)- FIND("-",A2)-1))
```

- couldn't return the correct value as there were too many symbols.

---

```
=RIGHT(A2,14) , =SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(C2,14),")","") , =datevalue
```

- couldn't pick up dates with one digit on the day.

---

[image: Data]

[image: with formulas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit longer version of your first formula but it works with examples you provided:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","@",(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")))/LEN("-")))+1,LEN(A1)- FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","@",(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")))/LEN("-")))-1))
```

It removes all "-" but the last one and does the same as you did with the rest of text.